# Shared constants in microservices approaches?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture, microservices

I have microservices written in PHP, Laravel. For a while, all configuration and constants were stored in .env file of each microservice. But, now these .env files have many repeated constants.

Can, someone, suggest what approaches can solve shared constants in microservices architecture.

Comment: It depends on the setup. Usually in a microservice architecture, you tend to use something like docker, kubernetes and such which often have solutions for dynamically populate the .env and similar for the different services so it's hard to suggest a good way without way more info. This questions might actually fit better over at [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) since it's more about server architecture than programming

Comment: Agreed that this question might be better at the other SE sites. Most consumer libraries allow you to populate "environment variables" from other key-value stores such as [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/features/#Parameter_Store).